# Is YouTube really showing the most-viewed videos on a channel?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to collect the most-viewed videos on a channel, sorted by views.

I realized that sometimes YouTube does not shows the real list of the most-viewed videos. I entered a channel and wrote down the 10 most-viewed videos. The next day I did the same thing and realized that the list had changed. Now, I could see at least three new videos with many views that were not shown the first time. When I tried again, these new videos were no longer.

I also did this with the API but these new videos are not listed.

I uploaded a screenshot showing these results:

http://i65.tinypic.com/sgtlef.png

In the screenshot you can see that, in the first search, the third most-viewed video has 211663 views, but in the second search the third video has now 195490. Where is the video with 211663 views?

It would be possible to get a complete list of most-viewed videos

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify it by using the [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) in the YouTube API. To get the list of most-viewed or popular video under of a specific channel, then you can pass these parameters in your request to the API.

```
part=snippet
channelId=CHANNEL_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK
maxResults=10  - it depends on you
order=viewCount
```

Here is the sample request for it.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCTjJEfopNLe7L5yXVv584Ww&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&_h=2&

And you can verify this information to the YouTube site itself

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTjJEfopNLe7L5yXVv584Ww/videos?flow=grid&sort=p&view=0

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that al The most-viewed vídeos are not always listed, as you can check in The image I posted. For sone reason i unknow, YouTube searcher omites or hides some vídeos with many views

Comment: Please, check this screenshot:

http://i65.tinypic.com/sgtlef.png

As you can see, YouTube shows different results for the same search criteria.

Thank you in advance